# How to declare a value in a trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers, declare

I am trying to write a trigger for my database using mysql and phpmyadmin. I have a database with a table for a client's information in which I store a credit card number and a table for hotel reservations where I store the client's way of paying.  I want my trigger to activate after update on client's info and if the credit card number is deleted to change the way of payment. The problem is that phpmyadmin does not compile it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_credit_card_update
AFTER UPDATE  
ON client
for each row
BEGIN
       declare cl_id int;
       IF ( (new.Credit_Card_Number = " ") or (new.Credit_Card_Number is null)) then
select into cl_id
                select reservation.Client_Id from 
reservation where ((reservation.Client_Id = new.Client_Id) and (reservation.Payment = 'Credit')) 
limit 1 ;
    update reservation
    set reservation.Payment = "NOT PAID"
    where reservation.Client_Id = cl_id;
END IF;
END$$
```

I believe that the problem is when I am declaring my value: cl_id

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'into cl_id select reservation.Client_Id from reservation where ' at line 8

FIXED :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_credit_card_update
AFTER UPDATE  
ON client
for each row
BEGIN
declare cl_id int;
IF ( (new.Credit_Card_Number = " ") or 
new.Credit_Card_Number is null)) then
 select reservation.Client_Id into cl_id from reservation 
here ((reservation.Client_Id = new.Client_Id) and 
reservation.Payment = 'credit')) 
limit 1 ;
update reservation
set reservation.Payment = "NOT PAID"
where reservation.Client_Id = cl_id;
END IF;
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Did you set the delimiter to `$$` before trying to create the procedure?

Comment: Yeap I did still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Not going into detail here, but you need to add `delimiter` statements before and after your trigger - so MySQL will know how to parse the code. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_credit_card_update
AFTER UPDATE  
ON client
for each row
BEGIN
       declare cl_id int;
       IF ( (new.Credit_Card_Number = " ") or 
new.Credit_Card_Number is null)) then
select into cl_id
                select reservation.Client_Id from 
reservation where reservation.Client_Id = new.Client_Id 
limit 1 ;
    update reservation
    set reservation.Payment = "NOT PAID"
    where reservation.Client_Id = cl_id;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I copy paste your solution and it is still not working